# Javadoc comments for an interface?

Tags: java, interface

I'm teaching myself Java and was hoping for feedback regarding this question:
Write a Java interface with two methods, one that adds two doubles together returning the sum and one that multiplies two doubles together returning the product. Use JavaDoc comments.

Am I missing anything? Is it appropriate to include @return in the JavaDoc comment for the interface?

```
/**
 * This is an interface for basic math.
 */
public interface Math {

  /**
   * This method will be used to add two doubles.
   * @param a a value to be added
   * @param b the other value to be added
   * @return the sum of the two doubles
   */
  public double add(double a, double b);

  /**
   * This method will be used to multiply two doubles.
   * @param a a value
   * @param b the other value
   * @return the product of the two doubles
   */
  public double multiply(double a, double b);

}
```

Comment: Please don't link to images of code.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: This is basically OK. You should always have an `@return` if there is a return value. You need to generate the Javadoc and see what the results look like to really decide. You could really omit 'this is [an interface]' and 'this method will be used to '.

Comment: In general, you could add tiny examples to your methods or the class description to make them easier to understand. However, in this case it is pretty much self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I missing anything?

There is nothing fundamentally wrong or "missing" from the javadocs in their current form.

> Is it appropriate to include @return in the JavaDoc comment for the interface?

It is absolutely appropriate.  An interface is a form of API, and meaning of the value returned by an API method is a fundamental aspect of the interface.  If the meaning of a method return value is not specified in an interface then a caller of the interface method can't know what to expect.  This makes *programming to the interface* difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is appropriate to have `@return`.

Few things you can improve:

- To follow Java coding conventions, start method names with lowercase
  (e.g. use `add` instead of `Add`).
- Have better parameter names. E.g.
  use `number1`, `number2` instead of `a`, `b`.
- Start `@param` and `@return` descriptions with uppercase letters (e.g. `@param number1 First number`).
- I thinks it is better to say `Returns the addition of two given numbers` than `This method will be used to add two doubles.`

Comment: How is `number1` better than `a`?

Comment: @user207421, because it says something about the parameter. `add(number1, number2)` is more meaningful than `add(a,b)`.

Comment: It says *what* about the parameter? It is more meaningful why? So far this is just waffle.

Comment: In general, I agree. You should use descriptive names. But in case of an `add` method, `a` and `b` is idiomatic and will be more readable than everything else. Same with `x`, `y` for coordinates. Also note that `number1` and `number2` are not really more helpful, `first` and `second` might be better, depending on the context.